# Using Powershell to pull services on multiple domain computers

Tags: powershell, service, scripting

My code currently is:

```
$Workstationlist=get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase 'OU=Workstations, DC=example, DC=com' -SearchScope 2 | foreach {$_.Name} 
foreach($workstation in $Workstationlist){ 
    get-service -ComputerName $workstation -name wauaserv

}
```

It seems to pulling service statuses from the array that is being parsed by the foreach method, but after a few values are returned it will spit this error message in between which seems to point at the location I saved the script

> Running  wuauserv           Windows Update
> Stopped  wuauserv           Windows Update
> Running  wuauserv           Windows Update
> Stopped  wuauserv           Windows Update
> get-service : Cannot find any service with service name 'wuauserv'. At
> \locationIsavedthescript

The idea is that I will stop the wauaserv service on all workstations in the domain, I was then going to add lines to delete everything from the \windowsdistrobution\ folder. And then restart the service. This effectively kills any downloading pending install update. I can drop $workstation into a **ls** snippet easy enough but pulling services doesn't seem to work quite as clean. Not sure why it is point the get-service to the location that I saved the script.

Any ideas and explanations as to how to accomplish what I'm shooting for a bit more cleanly or at least hide the erroneous output since the command IS running against the array.

I hope this made sense to someone out there.

Comment: add a `try/catch` block around the call, add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the call, and add code to show you what system failed in the `catch` block.

Comment: Typo: wauaserv in code example.  Should be: wuauserv